# How to use backslash in PEP8 when there is a dot or comma?

Tags: python-3.x, backslash, pep8

Here is my dataframe:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B'], 'col2':['C','D','D','D','C','C'], 
            'col3':[.1,.2,.4,.6,.8,1]})
In [3]: df
Out[4]: 
  col1 col2  col3
0    A    C   0.1
1    A    D   0.2
2    A    D   0.4
3    B    D   0.6
4    B    C   0.8
5    B    C   1.0
```

My question is: When I want to wrap the long text, where shall I put the backslash? After the dot or before the dot? Which is correct?

```
# option 1 backslash after dot or comma
df.groupby('col1').\
    sum()
df['col1'],\
    df['col2']

# option 2 backslash before dot or comma
df.groupby('col1')\
    .sum()
df['col1']\
    ,df['col2']
```

I also find that if I use parentheses I do not have to use the backslash. Then which option is correct?

```
# option 1: no backslash and dot or comma in the new line
(df.groupby('col1')
    .sum())
(df['col1']
    ,df['col2'])

# option 2: no backslash and dot or comma in the old line
(df.groupby('col1').
    sum())
(df['col1'],
    df['col2'])

# option 3: backslash after dot or comma 
(df.groupby('col1').\
    sum())
(df['col1'],\
    df['col2'])

# option 4: backslash before dot or comma 
(df.groupby('col1')\
    .sum())
(df['col1']\
    ,df['col2'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

[PEP8 prefers usage of brackets over backslashes where it's possible](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

PEP8 doesn't say anything about dots or commas needing to be on the same line as the expression (though it's like that in every example given).

## Solution

The technically correct answers would be:

```py
# option 1: no backslash and dot or comma in the new line
(df.groupby('col1')
    .sum())
(df['col1']
    ,df['col2'])

# option 2: no backslash and dot or comma in the old line
(df.groupby('col1').
    sum())
(df['col1'],
    df['col2'])
```

Though [one could argue that the recommendation against space between a trailing comma and closing parenthesis is the exception that proves the rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741418/pep8-space-after-a-comma?rq=1#comment78603168_37064013), which would mean that: `,df['col2']` doesn't follow the standards (though `, df['col2']` still does).

Even though the 2 options presented above are technically correct, the following is the *most commonly* used:

```py
(df.groupby('col1')
    .sum())
(df['col1'],
    df['col2'])
```

> Note: the [indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) depends in the context it's used. The examples above shouldn't be used as reference. Also remember that [PEP8 is just a guideline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds), there are many scenarios where the rules should be broken in order to improve readability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python, I shall put '+' in the first line. Does it means: it is better to put ',' and operator in first line. Put other symbol in the second line?

Comment: [No, you shouldn't put `+` on the first line](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator). Placing `+` on the second line is preferred by PEP8. That means that only commas (`,`) stay on the first line, while binary operators and member of object access operator (`.`) go on the second line. I can't say much for 'other symbols', as it really depends on the context.